# Module not found: Can't resolve --> For NEXT JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I just created a new NEXT JS project using the automatic installation method, however I receive errors that regarding module not found.

```
- error ./
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\app\favicon.ico?__next_metadata__'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error ./
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\app\favicon.ico?__next_metadata__'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
- wait compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
- error ./:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\app\favicon.ico?__next_metadata_route__'
  4 | import { RouteKind } from "next/dist/server/future/route-kind";
  5 | // @ts-expect-error - replaced by webpack/turbopack loader
> 6 | import * as userland from "next-metadata-route-loader?page=%2Ffavicon.ico%2Froute&isDynamic=0!D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\app\\favicon.ico?__next_metadata_route__";
  7 | const AppRouteRouteModule = module.AppRouteRouteModule;
  8 | // We inject the nextConfigOutput here so that we can use them in the route
  9 | // module.
```

I have tried removing the favicon entirely, however the error changes to google fonts being a problem:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error ../../../../C#/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXT JS/experimentation_app/app/layout.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/font/google/target.css?{"path":"app\\layout.js","import":"Inter","arguments":[{"subsets":["latin"]}],"variableName":"inter"}'
```

However the more I try to fix it the more errors pop up

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../../C#/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXT JS/experimentation_app/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/constants.js'
Require stack:
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\render-server.js
- D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\processChild.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:110:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at ../shared/lib/constants (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:82:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (eval at ../../../../C#/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXT JS/experimentation_app/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:42:1), <anonymous>:33:20)
    at ../../../../C#/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXT JS/experimentation_app/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:42:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:122:39)
    at D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:123:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:126:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at requirePage (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:112:75)
    at D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:76:65
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async loadComponentsImpl (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:75:33)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (D:\POST\DEVELOPMENT\C#\HoosainTachnologyLabs\NEXT JS\experimentation_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:439:36) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\.next\\server\\pages\\_document.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\require.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next-server.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\dev\\next-dev-server.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\render-server.js',
    'D:\\POST\\DEVELOPMENT\\C#\\HoosainTachnologyLabs\\NEXT JS\\experimentation_app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\jest-worker\\processChild.js'
  ]
}
```

Please note I am new to NEXT JS 13, my Node JS is the latest 18.*., I tried using an older version of NEXT JS and what baffles me is that this is a new project with no changes directly after npx create. Please advise, am I installing it incorrectly or is my setup wrong. What can I do?

TLDR: I am getting a bunch of module not found errors on a fresh npx create project, not sure what to do.

Comment: If your project folder is `NEXT JS` with a space, try to remove the space.

Comment: My greetings @YoussoufOumar I renamed the folder the errors did persist. I recreated the project to try it in the start state again, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem has been solved by now. I had same problem. You should change your path "../**C#**/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXT JS" to "../**Csharp**/HoosainTachnologyLabs/NEXTJS". Apparently, it is sensitive to symptoms. You could check **_document.js** file in ".next/server/pages/".

Answer (score 0):

I found what's the problem and any errors that happen in the first. My project path of was "/var/www/html/C#/nextApp". While better be this: "/var/www/html/Csharp/nextApp". Apparently, it is sensitive to symptoms. I found this problem from _document.js in ".next/server/pages/".